# Android & AndroidJUnit4. How to handle & test indeterminate lifecycle loop error

Tags: java, android, integration-testing, android-lifecycle, android-junit

Errors connected with infinite loops of view events are the topic of this question. Such loops don't throw `StackOverflowError`, because are executed very frequently, but not recursively. An example of that code error could be `invalidate()` call inside `onDraw` of custom view.

By default *AndroidJUnit4* waits for app idle after starting a test activity and then performs verifications. But in case of infinite lifecycle loop idle won't be achieved and test will fail with error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent within 45 seconds. Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time?`
Such error isn't so declarative and test have to wait for it so long.

*For example*,
I should test `onLayoutChildren` method of `LayoutManager`. By default in case properly implementation this method is executed two or three times after start and that's all. And this test is passed
`verify(spy, atMost(3)).onLayoutChildren(any(RecyclerView.Recycler.class), any(RecyclerView.State.class))`, where `spy` is a spy of `LayoutManager`. A behaviour could be corrupted and `onLayoutChildren` goes to infinite loop. In case of error under test it stucks.

**What i am trying to achive**. Possible variant is run test & application for some time (like 500ms or so) then break the app and perform verifications after that. Without any connection to idle

Comment: Ps: i can't get `Activity` from `ActivityTestRule` until activity have been launched to stop it manually after a while